# CircuitPython Error: ImportError: no module named 'adafruit_hid'

Tags: keyboard, hid

I am trying to setup a HID keyboard with a Raspberry Pico and I get error above when I try to run the code shown below:

```
import time
import board
import digitalio
import usb_hid
from adafruit_hid.keyboard import Keyboard
from adafruit_hid.keycode import Keycode

b1_pin = board.GP15
keyboard = Keyboard(usb_hid.devices)
b1 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(b1_pin)
b1.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
b1.pull = digitalio.Pull.DOWN
while true:
    if b1.value:
        Print("GPIO15 Pressed")
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

adafruit_hid is an external library you can get from the bundle: https://circuitpython.org/libraries. Make sure you add it to the board.

For general info about libraries: https://learn.adafruit.com/welcome-to-circuitpython/circuitpython-libraries